# Why does the BitArray constructor parameter fulfills as count with a Byte?

Tags: c#

I've had some frustrating issues with my code when converting a `byte` to a `BitArray`. I managed to work out that the issue was down to passing a `byte` into the `BitArray` constructor rather than the accepted `byte[]`. By passing a `byte`, it led to the compiler to passing my `byte` parameter as an `int` which fulfilled the count parameter and I was none the wiser.

How come the compiler does not scream when passing a `byte` as it's not one of the accepted parameters in the constructor? Also, why did it convert my `byte` to an `int` to fulfil the count parameter?

- You can find the `BitArray` class along with constructor info here at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Example code:

```
var bytesData = new[] {0xc4, 0x6e};
BitArray arr = new BitArray(bytesData[0]);
```

Result:

[image]

*In case anyone else is unsure on the Implicit Numeric Conversions, you can find the official table [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/implicit-numeric-conversions-table).*

Comment: Can you show how you were calling it with a single byte?

Comment: @RonBeyer exactly as above using an index from a `byte` array

Comment: Are you asking why `byte` is implicitly convertible to `int`, or are you asking why there isn't a specific exception to deny the conversion in this context?

Comment: Missed that, thought it was the entire array. Yes, you are getting an implicit conversion here to `int`.

Comment: @hvd I am asking because although similar, they are two different types and didn't realise that you could use the them interchangeably.

Comment: @RonBeyer Thanks Ron. Will have to be more careful in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How come the compiler does not scream when passing a byte as it's not one of the accepted parameters in the constructor?

Because there's an implicit conversion from `byte` to `int`. For example, this is fine too:

```
int foo = bytesData[0];
```

This is perfectly normal within C# - it just happens not to be the behavior you want. Overload resolution looks at all the available constructors:

- `BitArray(BitArray)`
- `BitArray(bool[])`
- `BitArray(byte[])`
- `BitArray(int)`
- `BitArray(int, bool)`
- `BitArray(int[])`

When you provide a single argument of type `byte`, the only one of these that's applicable is the `BitArray(int)` constructor, so that's what's called.

Comment: I never knew that. Thank you for confirming!